# making a square div within a row a vertical rectangle?

Tags: html, css, grid-layout

I have created a responsivee grid layout and its all working wonderfully, however now the last thing I need to do is to make a couple of the squares rectangular.

The ones I need to make rectangular are the top two squares in the second column of my grid and the last two squares in the bottom row of my grid. A you can see I have done the horizontal rectangle, now I need to do the same vertically with the top two squares in the second column.

Can somebody please show me how to do this and keep the spinning action as I have tried it and not been able to do it properly.

Thanks

***CSS***

```
.trigger{
    width:200px; 
    height:200px; 
    margin-right:15px;
    margin-bottom:15px; 
}
.hover-img, 
.hover-img.hover_effect  {
    background-color:white;
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 0;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none; 
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: #4595ff;
}
.trigger:hover > .hover-img {
     -webkit-transform:rotateY(360deg);
    -moz-transform:rotateY(360deg);
    -ms-transform:rotateY(360deg);
    -o-transform:rotateY(360deg);
    transform:rotateY(360deg);
    font-size:14px;
    color:white;
}

.img1 {
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat; 
}
.img1:hover{
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.img2 {
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.img2:hover{
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.img3 {
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
} 
.img3:hover{
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.img4 {
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.img4:hover{
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.img5 {
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.img5:hover{
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.img6 {
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.img6:hover{
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#container{
    width:960px; margin: 0 auto;
}

.row{
    display: flex;
}
```

***HTML***

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="trigger">
            <div tabindex="0" class="maincontent hover-img img1"> </div>
        </div>
        <div class="trigger">
            <div tabindex="0" class="maincontent hover-img img2"> </div>
        </div>
        <div class="trigger">
            <div tabindex="0" class="maincontent hover-img img3"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="trigger">
            <div tabindex="0" class="maincontent hover-img img4"> </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div  class="row">
        <div class="trigger">
            <div tabindex="0" class="maincontent hover-img img5"> </div>
        </div>
        <div class="trigger">
            <div tabindex="0" class="maincontent hover-img img6"> </div>
        </div>
        <div class="trigger">
            <div tabindex="0" class="maincontent hover-img img5"> </div>
        </div>
        <div class="trigger">
            <div tabindex="0" class="maincontent hover-img img6"> </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div  class="row">
        <div class="trigger">
            <div tabindex="0" class="maincontent hover-img img5"> </div>
        </div>
        <div class="trigger">
            <div tabindex="0" class="maincontent hover-img img6"> </div>
        </div>
        <div class="trigger">
            <div tabindex="0" class="maincontent hover-img img5"> </div>
        </div>
        <div class="trigger">
            <div tabindex="0" class="maincontent hover-img img6"> </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Do you need the same number of divs?

Comment: `.large` selector is the rectangular box and it's equal to two square boxes ...

Comment: I have already done the horizontal rectangle, all I need to work out how to do is the vertical one :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you given a try to `flex-wrap` in a single `.row` container ??

Use however your `.large` class or `nth-child()`.

```css
.trigger{
    width:200px; 
    height:20px; 
    margin-right:15px;
    margin-bottom:15px; 
  box-shadow:0 0 0 2px;/* or border + box-sizing */
}
#container .row{
    width:960px; margin: 0 auto;
    display: flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
}
.trigger.large {
  width:415px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="trigger">
      <div tabindex="0" class="maincontent hover-img img1"> </div>
    </div>
    <div class="trigger large">
      <div tabindex="0" class="maincontent hover-img img2"> </div>
    </div>
    <div class="trigger">
      <div tabindex="0" class="maincontent hover-img img3"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="trigger">
      <div tabindex="0" class="maincontent hover-img img4"> </div>
    </div>
    <div class="trigger">
      <div tabindex="0" class="maincontent hover-img img5"> </div>
    </div>
    <div class="trigger large">
      <div tabindex="0" class="maincontent hover-img img6"> </div>
    </div>
    <div class="trigger">
      <div tabindex="0" class="maincontent hover-img img5"> </div>
    </div>
    <div class="trigger large">
      <div tabindex="0" class="maincontent hover-img img6"> </div>
    </div>
    <div class="trigger">
      <div tabindex="0" class="maincontent hover-img img5"> </div>
    </div>
    <div class="trigger large">
      <div tabindex="0" class="maincontent hover-img img6"> </div>
    </div>
    <div class="trigger large">
      <div tabindex="0" class="maincontent hover-img img5"> </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Hi @GCyrillus I have done the horizontal one, I just need to do the vertical rectange that I need, the problem is because I am using rows will having a  taller rectangle distort the whole row?

Answer (score 0):

Increase the width of the 3rd column trigger and hide the 4th column trigger.  Example  [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MYQKKE)

Css

```
.row:first-child .trigger:nth-child(3),
.row:first-child .trigger:nth-child(3) .img3 {
  width: 415px;
}
.row:first-child .trigger:nth-child(4) {
  display:none;
}

.row:nth-child(3) .trigger:nth-child(3),
.row:nth-child(3) .trigger:nth-child(3) .img5 {
  width: 415px;
}
.row:nth-child(3) .trigger:nth-child(4) {
  display:none;
}
```

Comment: Hi @Justin I have done the horizontal one, I just need to do the vertical rectange that I need, the problem is because I am using rows will having a  taller rectangle distort the whole row?

Comment: @stevie peters yeah, I'd think you would have to use absolute positioning to do that.  You could maybe use a simple js library such as masonjs, http://masonjs.com/ to accomplish this.  This wouldn't scale but you could just re-stack/size with media queries.